# Unable to run cocos2dx game with admobs banner

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I tried to implement an AdMob in the cocos2dx project via android studio and got the following message after the build succeeded. The app doesn't run. I've set the gradle, manifest file, AppActivity in android studio folder.

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.test.puzzle/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sample.mygame/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity } from null (pid=27372, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10466
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2174)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.puzzle"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/puzzle">

        <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so-->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                   android:value="MyGame" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <activity
            android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

AppActivity

```
package org.cocos2dx.cpp;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {

    private AdView _adView;
    private final String AD_UNIT_ID = "xxx";  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.gravity = (Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER); 

        _adView = new AdView(this);
        _adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        _adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)    
                .addTestDevice("Test Device ID")                
                .build();

        _adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        _adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        addContentView(_adView, adParams);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (_adView != null) {
            _adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (_adView != null) {
            _adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        _adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to integrated with c++ or Java ?

Comment: Since I'm trying to add admobs for android. I've altered the files in the android-studio folder.

Comment: Please show your `AndoridManifest.xml` file

Comment: I've added the manifest file

Comment: Are you using Run Configuration of Android Studio to run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set android:exported="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml file of this Activity.

```
<activity
 ----
android:exported="true">

</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove below `Activity` from your `AndroidManifest.xml`, not required to display banner Ad.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:exported="true"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Second thing from where are you calling/starting new Intent for   `com.test.puzzle/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity`

Comment: Seems that I needed android:exported="true". Now seems like it's working.